# How to reduce Prisma select(or include) field code line

Tags: mysql, express, prisma

I am developing with prisma + express + javascript + mysql
prisma version is 2.28,
I have a problem while using prisma.
when the model is

```
model User{
  id              Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  email           String        @unique @db.VarChar(30)
  password        String?       @db.VarChar(200)
  nickname        String?       @unique @db.VarChar(30)
  profile         Profile?

}
model Profile {
  id             Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  department     String?          @db.VarChar(50)
  introduce      String?          @db.Text
  createdAt      DateTime
  updatedAt      DateTime?
  user           User             @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId         Int
  wellTalent     WellTalent[]
  interestTalent InterestTalent[]
  profileImage   Image?

  @@map(name: "profiles")
}
model InterestTalent {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  contents  String?
  createdAt DateTime
  updatedAt DateTime?
  profile   Profile   @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id])
  profileId Int

  @@map(name: "interest_talents")
}

model WellTalent {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  contents  String?
  createdAt DateTime
  updatedAt DateTime?
  profile   Profile   @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id])
  profileId Int

  @@map(name: "well_talents")
}

model Image {
  id        Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  src       String?   @db.VarChar(200)
  createdAt DateTime
  updatedAt DateTime?
  profile   Profile?  @relation(fields: [profileId], references: [id])
  profileId Int?

  @@map(name: "images")
}
```

if i want to find the profile data along with user table

```js
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const findByIdWithProfile = async (id) => {
    try {
        return await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: { id },
            select: {
                id: true,
                nickname: true,
                email: true,
                profile: {
                    select: {
                        id: true,
                        department: true,
                        introduce: true,
                        wellTalent: {
                            select: {
                                contents: true,
                            },
                        },
                        interestTalent: {
                            select: {
                                contents: true,
                            },
                        },
                        profileImage: {
                            select: {
                                src: true,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

code line is very increase..
i can find User table and Profile table separately, but nest query use to minimize DB access.
bigger the project, the worse it got.
It seems that the DB structure is structured incorrectly, but the cost is already too high to replace, and I do not know which way is the best.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, could you clarify if returning the very specific selection of fields is a requirement? If it's not necessary, then you could just return all the fields of a certain relation using ```include``` instead of ```select```. If this is an important requirement, then I'm afraid you will have to specify the fields manually like you're doing now. The best you could do is make the code less verbose and easier to read by putting multiple key-value pairs of the ```select``` statements in the same line.

Comment: First, thanks for your comment. Using `select` is not an important requirement. i just used it to get specific data without returning id needed relation( password in the User table is different), if no requirements, is it correct to use `include` ? 
I think the code will be more concise than select. I was just wondering if there is a function that Prisma provides or if there is another db-level approach! @TasinIshmam

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you need manual control of exactly which fields are fetched, it's better to go with the `include` keyword.

Here is a more succinct version of your query with the `include` keyword instead of `select`.

```js
const findByIdWithProfile = async (id) => {
    try {
        let data = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: { id },
            include: {
                profile: {
                    include: {
                        wellTalent: true,
                        interestTalent: true,
                        profileImage: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        });
        delete data["password"]; // sensitive information we don't want to expose. 
        return data; 
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

You mentioned in the comments that the only field you want to omit is `password`. Here I manually omitted that field using the `delete` keyword once the data is fetched. There's currently no Prisma feature to explicitly "exclude" certain fields but keep everything else. However, this feature is currently being worked one and should be available soon. You can track progress in [this github issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7380).

Comment: The method you suggested looks very good. I knew delete method , but i didn't think of it.. thank you , I hope that is excluded from schema is provided soon.

Comment: Happy to help. Please feel free to [join our slack](https://slack.prisma.io/) to get regular feature updates or ask if you have any questions!