# Prisma Reading data - is there a better way to read nested data?

Tags: javascript, database, prisma

I currently need to pull lots of nested data to format into a JavaScript object to send into a chart as the data, I am currently allowing ten nested deep, but there might be some cases when this just keeps on going.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to pull out data like this, I couldn't see anything in the docs, for pulling infinitely or dynamically nested data through the relationships.

This is what I currently have for example:

```
const [result] = await prisma.company.findMany({
  where: {
    users: {
      some: {
        email: {
          contains: session.user.email,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  select: {
    name: true,
    users: true,
    id: true,
    profiles: {
      select: {
        id: true,
        name: true,
        image: true,
        category: {
          select: { name: true },
        },
        children: {
          select: {
            id: true,
            name: true,
            image: true,
            category: {
              select: { name: true },
            },
            children: {
              select: {
                id: true,
                name: true,
                image: true,
                category: {
                  select: { name: true },
                },
                children: {
                  select: {
                    id: true,
                    name: true,
                    image: true,
                    category: {
                      select: { name: true },
                    },
                    children: {
                      select: {
                        id: true,
                        name: true,
                        image: true,
                        category: {
                          select: { name: true },
                        },
                        children: {
                          select: {
                            id: true,
                            name: true,
                            image: true,
                            category: {
                              select: { name: true },
                            },
                          },
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the `include` statement instead of `select`? It automatically fetches all non-relation fields, so you just have to manually specify the relation fields. [The nested reads section](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries/#nested-reads) in the prisma docs also contains a lot of examples for this.

In general, if you don't need granular control over which fields of the model get returned from the query, `include` is the way to go.

[Please check out my answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69319651/how-to-reduce-prisma-selector-include-field-code-line/69366147#69366147). I think you might find that solution relevant to your use-case.

Comment: Hmm, I previously had it as include, but this didn’t include them nested relationships all the way down, unless I did something wrong. I’ll try it again. And gave me too much data for the chart - probably not an issue, but felt it was cleaner with less data.

Comment: You can nest `include` as many levels as you want, so you can 5-6 levels of nesting similar to what you're doing with `select` here. However it's less verbose because you only need to specify the `relation` fields, the data fields get returned automatically.  Regarding returning less data though from the query though: this is a tradeoff you're going to have to make. `include` will return more data but the code will be more concise and the opposite is true for `select`. Unfortunately, you can't have both.